# Пунктуация: помогите расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложении:

**Поддон вы можете приобрести отдельно: от экономичного акрилового до элитного мраморного.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире вместо двоеточия ("отдельно" не раскрывает содержимого).

Вот если бы:

***Поддон вы можете приобрести отдельно, вариантов множество: от экономичного акрилового до элитного мраморного.***

К примеру.

Или (лучше и ближе к тексту оригинала):

***Отдельно вы можете приобрести поддон: от экономичного акрилового до элитного мраморного.***

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, Галина!

Comment: Не за что. ))) Катюша, Вы новичок на проекте, поэтому сообщаю: если ответ, и не один, оказался полезным, нужно кликнуть по стрелочке вверх, а тот окончательный, который Вы сочтёте в полной мере всё разъясняющим (я не указала правило, на которое опираться, - надо?), обрадовать кликом по галочке, что ниже стрелки, смотрящей вниз - её не трогать! она означает минус ответу! - и вручить автору ЛОшечку - ЛУЧШИЙ ОТВЕТ. Это стимул для отвечающих! )))

Comment: Спасибо, Галина, вам еще раз, и за разъяснения, и за вводный курс) :-)

Comment: Да, Катя, ещё одна проектная тонкость: если придут другие ответы, эту зазеленевшую галочку можно "передарить" - по ситуации. Она не окончательно приделана! )))

Comment: Какая Вы молодец! Побольше бы таких форумчан! :-)